# Eloquent query that checks a collection on a collection of emails for approvers who have approved each email when not all have approval_status

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm really close on this, but it's not quite catching all scenarios. There's a collection of emails. They can each have multiple reviews (for sure at least one). The review will have an `approver_status` property (the reviewer attached to this review can approve or deny it) and an `approved` property (whether it is actually approved to be sent or not). Some reviewers are not "approvers" and can only give feedback. My eloquent query looks like this:

```
 $data = Email::with('emailReviews')
                 ->where(['created_by' => $personID, 'sent_at' => null])
                 ->get()
                 ->map(function ($email) {
                     $reviewsStatus = $email->emailReviews->pluck('approved')->unique();
                     if ($reviewsStatus->count() == 1 && $reviewsStatus->first()) {
                         $email->approvalStatus = true;
                     } else {
                         $email->approvalStatus = false;
                     }

                     return $email;
                 });
```

It works if all reviewers are "approvers", but if there are some reviews with approvers and non-approvers, it sends back false even if all of the "approvers" have approved it. In the map function I need to ignore the `approved` property if a reviewer does not have `approver_status`. I was wondering if I could add something to the line:

```
$reviewsStatus = $email->emailReviews->pluck('approved')->unique();
```

that basically acts as a where clause `where approver_status === false`. I know I can't do that, but that's the idea. I've also tried some adding an if statement in there:

```
$data = Email::with('emailReviews')
                 ->where(['created_by' => $personID, 'sent_at' => null])
                 ->get()
                 ->map(function ($email) {
                     $approverStatus = $email->emailReviews->pluck('approver_status')->unique();
                     if ($approverStatus->count() == 1 && $approverStatus->first()) {
                         $reviewsStatus = $email->emailReviews->pluck('approved')->unique();
                         if ($reviewsStatus->count() == 1 && $reviewsStatus->first()) {
                             $email->approvalStatus = true;
                         } else {
                             $email->approvalStatus = false;
                         }
                     }

                     return $email;
                 });
```

This is just not returning an `$email->approvalStatus` for the emails with the more complex review scenarios. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the emailReviews where both the approved and the approver_status is set to true, then set the approvalStatus to true if there's at at least one count.

```
$data = Email::with('emailReviews')
    ->where(['created_by' => $personId, 'sent_at' => null])
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($email) {
        $email->approvalStatus = $email->emailReviews->where('approved', true)
            ->where('approver_status', true)
            ->count() > 0;

        return $email;
    });
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a million.

Comment: @MattLarson No problem, have a nice day! :)

Comment: You as well! 